# C# Using a variable created with Class, in another part of script

Tags: c#, function, class, unity-game-engine

Trying to use in a function a variable created at the start of the script with a Class. The error says "The name 'celula' does not exist in the current context".

It is supposed that celula.Name must return "Cel1".

```
public class ScreenC : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Start()
    {
        Cel celula = new Cel("Cel1", 30);
    }
    public class Cel
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get;
        }
        public int ATP
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public Cel(string nm, int atp)
        {
            this.Name = nm;
            this.ATP = atp;
        }
    }
    public void ADDTHESE()
    {                 //here it seems to be the error
        GameObject.Find(celula.Name).GetComponent<Text>().text = "ATP = 50";
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to declare the variable outside of the `Start` method if you want to use it outside of that method. Declare it as `private Cel celula;` at the class level, and then it will be available to all methods within the class.